# Statistics of list permutations - expected similarity of rankings?

Tags: statistics, permutations

I created a website where users create rankings, so for each user I have an ordered list of distinct elements $[e_1, e_2, ..., e_n]$

I calculate the similarity of two users by summing up the absolute index differences for each element and dividing the result by the [maximum possible total difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743916/maximum-possible-sum-of-index-differences-of-two-lists) ($ \lfloor n^2/2 \rfloor $), then subtracting that from one.

Users with similarity 1 have the exact same ranking.

Now it seems that for most users the average difference to all other users isn't 50%, but below that. I calculated the difference for all permutations for $n=10$ from one specific ranking and got this result:

[image]

and this seems to confirm this phenomenon - assuming that user rankings (element permutations) are random, the average similarity to other users is indeed less than 50%. But why? What kind of distribution is this and what is its most common value for a given $n$?

Since with $n$ elements, there are $n!$ possible permutations, it isn't possible to "brute-force-plot" this for large n, unless (randomly) sampling a subset which I've done here:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question, but [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492954/distance-between-two-permutations) are some other notions of distance between permutations that may interest you.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://finmath.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/77_04_spearmans.pdf

Comment: The expected sum of absolute ranking differences is $\frac13(n^2-\frac1n)$ which is nearer two-thirds rather than half your $\lfloor n^2/2 \rfloor$ for $n>2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference Catalin Zara gave to [Diaconis and Graham](https://finmath.stanford.edu/%7Ecgates/PERSI/papers/77_04_spearmans.pdf) in the comments provides the information you need.  This is also sequence [A062869](https://oeis.org/A062869) in OEIS.  Following Diaconis and Graham, let$$
D(\pi,\sigma)=\sum_{i=1}^n|\pi(i) - \sigma(i)|.
$$
The statistics of $D(\pi,\sigma)$ over $\pi$ are the same for any $\sigma$, so we only need to consider $D(\pi) = D(1,\pi)$, where $1$ denotes the identity permutation.  Your statistic is$$
S(\pi) = 1-\frac{1}{\lfloor n^2/2 \rfloor} D(\pi).
$$
Diaconis and Graham state that $D$ approaches a normal distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and that the asymptotic mean and variance are $\mathbb{E}[D] = n^2/3$ and $\mathrm{var}[D] = 2n^3/45$.  Therefore the $S$ is also asymptotically normal with asymptotic mean and variance equal to $$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[S]&=\frac{1}{3},\;\text{and}\\
\mathrm{var}[S]&=\frac{8}{45n}.
\end{align}
$$
In particular, for $n=100$ the asymptotic mean of $1/3$, the asymptotic standard deviation of $0.042$, and the asymptotic normality of the distribution are all consistent with your histogram.